# L^2 estimate of the laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I was trying to solve problem 7 in chapter 5(sobolev spaces) in evans. The first part requires to show that for all test functions $u$, we have $$\bigg(\int{|Du|^2}\bigg)^2 \leq C \int |u|^2 \cdot \int |D^2u|^2  $$

By integration by parts we have $\int |Du|^2 = -\int u\Delta u$  and then by cauchy ineqaulity we get the desired inequality with $\Delta u$ in place of $D^2u$ . My question is that is it obvious that $\int |\Delta u|^2 \leq \int |D^2u|^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing an estimate like
$$
(\sum_{i=1}^n \partial_i^2u)^2 \le n \sum_{i=1}^n (\partial_i^2u)^2
$$
gives you a constant that depends on space dimension. To get rid of this dependence, one has to integrate by parts again:
$$
\int |\Delta u|^2 = \int (\sum_i \partial_i^2u)^2 = \int \sum_i\sum_j \partial_i^2u \cdot \partial_j^2 u
= \int \sum_i\sum_j (\partial_i \partial_j u)^2 = \int |D^2u|^2.
$$

---

Side note: integration by parts is used in the second to last equality, under the assumption of zero boundary condition. In general, we would have

$$
\int_U \partial_i^2 u  \,\partial_j^2 u = \int_U (\partial_i  \partial_j u)^2 
+ \int_{\partial U} \partial_i u \,(\partial_i \partial_j u \,\nu_j- \partial_j \partial_j u \,\nu_i)
$$
where $\nu_i$ is the $i$-th component of boundary normal.

Comment: I'm not so sure $\| a \|_{\ell^1_n} \leq \sqrt{n} \| a\|_{\ell^2_n}$ would be called the triangle inequality but I can't really give it a better name

Comment: @CalvinKhor  you are right, modified.

Comment: I think your last equality was supposed to be an inequality?

Comment: It depends on the definition of $|D^2u|$. Usually the $H^2$-norm is defined to contain the second order terms of the second-to-last expression, thats why I wrote equality.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I thought that was Holder.